# Nodejs 12 Callback not working for mysql connection?

Tags: mysql, node.js, aws-lambda

I'm writing this code to run in AWS Lambda.

Looking at [mysql](https://npm.runkit.com/mysql#connection-options) connection documentation

I expect, if things are working with out errors, to get the message "Database connected successfully!"
**and then** to get a message "connected as id " but that is not the order that it is happening.  Here is my code.

```
'use strict';

let mysql = require('mysql');

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  dateStrings: true,
  host     : process.env.rds_host,
  user     : process.env.rds_user,
  password : process.env.rds_password,
  database : process.env.rds_database,
  port     : process.env.rds_port
});

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC';
  let data = null;
  console.log('\nGetCompanies SQL: ', sql);
  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode   = 0;

  connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
      statusCode = 500;
      responseBody = err;
    }
    else{
      console.log("Database connected successfully!");
      statusCode = 200;
      responseBody = "Database connected successfully!";
    }
  });
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

  connection.query(sql, data, function(queryError, results) {
    if(queryError) {
      console.error(queryError.message);
      callback(queryError);
    }
    else
    {
      console.log('\nGetCompanies Results: ', results[0]);
      callback(null, results);
    }
  });
};
```

Here is the logged output:

INFO
GetCompanies SQL:  SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC 2020-01-01T11:52:57.813Z

INFO    **connected as id null** 2020-01-01T11:52:57.**952Z**

INFO    **Database connected successfully!** 2020-01-01T11:52:57.**974Z**

My thought was that the function that I supply to:

```
connection.connect(function(err) {
```

would execute before any code after connection.connect.  Am I wrong to think that?

One more question:  Why is the

> **connected as id null**?  I got that code (connection.threadId) straight from the [mysql](https://npm.runkit.com/mysql#connection-options) docs.

I know this is no big deal if all it effects is the order of log messages but I have other functions where I can't make queries because the connection isn't there yet.

It's quite confusing when it blows right past the

```
if (err) {
  statusCode = 500;
  responseBody = err;
}
else{
  <do some connection.query code here>
}
```

I put these log messages here because this method works and my other method doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
would execute before any code after connection.connect. Am I wrong to think that?
```

- The function you are passing to the `connection.connect` is called a
  callback function. what that mean is, it will be called only after a
  successful connection(or after the connection attempt is errored) is made. So the answer is no. The `connection.connect` is called and then immediately it will call the next statement. It will not wait for the current statement, because javascript is event driven and non blocking.

> connected as id null? I got that code (connection.threadId) straight from the mysql docs.

- This is because of the previous statement, you are logging the connectionId before a connection is obtained.

#### using Callbacks

Your code should be like the below. I haven't modified much, the connection to the database is made only after the callback of the connect event is called.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC';
  let data = null;
  console.log('\nGetCompanies SQL: ', sql);
  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode = 0;

  connection.connect(function (err) {

    // we are inside the callback function a successful connection has been obtained , or error connecting to database
    if (err) {
      statusCode = 500;
      responseBody = err;
    }
    else {
      console.log("Database connected successfully!");
      statusCode = 200;
      responseBody = "Database connected successfully!";
    }

    // connection exists
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

    connection.query(sql, data, function (queryError, results) {
      if (queryError) {
        console.error(queryError.message);
        callback(queryError);
      }
      else {
        console.log('\nGetCompanies Results: ', results[0]);
        callback(null, results);
      }
    });
  });
};
```

#### using promises

If you could use promises to make your code readable and understandable.

```
import { promisify } from 'util';
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC';
  let data = null;
  console.log('\nGetCompanies SQL: ', sql);

  const connect = promisify(connection.connect);
  const query = promisify(connection.query);

  try {
    const connection = await connect();

    // connection exists
    console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
    const results= await query(sql);

    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      responseBody: JSON.stringify(results)
    }

  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: 500,
      responseBody: err.message
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Ok got it.  :-)  Thanks for the quick reply. So everything I want to do after the connection needs to be in the connections callback. or handled with a promise.

Comment: @arun-k It's customary if you use part of someone else's answer to quote them at least :)

Comment: @KingAndrew correct. Nothing wrong in using callbacks. It's just that async/await is clean. Note the usage of `util.promisify` . It's handy because its used to convert a callback to a promise

Comment: @T.Short sorry you feel it that way. But that's not true. I think you are talking about the promises part. If you look at carefully, I am using typescript for imports and also using promisify. If you mean that I used your answer, that's not true because, you are awaiting on `connection.connect`. You cannot await on a statement with callback.

Comment: @ArunK do I need an await in front of query(sql)?  If not why?

Comment: Yes, I missed it. Updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

You are getting that behaviour because `console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);` is not waiting for `connection.connect` to finish connecting.

You need to use [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) here.

You could try to use `async/await`.

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
    context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

    let sql = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC';
    let data = null;
    console.log('\nGetCompanies SQL: ', sql);
    let responseBody = "";
    let statusCode   = 0;

    try {
        await connection.connect();

        console.log("Database connected successfully!");
        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

        const queryResult = await connection.query(sql, data);

        // do something with queryResult
    } catch (e) {
        // handle error
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

The resource you linked to suggests to use promises over callbacks:

> await any promise instead of using callbacks

Answer (score 1):

You should move your connection.query statement into the connection.connect scope as even if you can not connect to database you will try to make a query which is not working properly.

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  //prevent timeout from waiting event loop
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;

  let sql = 'SELECT * FROM company ORDER BY points DESC, name ASC';
  let data = null;
  console.log('\nGetCompanies SQL: ', sql);
  let responseBody = "";
  let statusCode   = 0;

  connection.connect(function(err) {
  if (err) {
      statusCode = 500;
      responseBody = err;
    }
    else{
      console.log("Database connected successfully!");
      statusCode = 200;
      responseBody = "Database connected successfully!";
      connection.query(sql, data, function(queryError, results) {
        if(queryError) {
          console.error(queryError.message);
          callback(queryError);
        }
        else
        {
          console.log('\nGetCompanies Results: ', results[0]);
          callback(null, results);
        }
      });
    }
  });
  console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);

};
```