# How to query an AWS Aurora MySQL database has been scaled to 0 ACUs

Tags: mysql, node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless, amazon-aurora

I am using AWS Amazon RDS Aurora serverless database for an API data source.

- Aurora 2.08.3 compatible with MySQL 5.7

I have enabled the "Pause after inactivity feature" to "Scale the capacity to 0 ACUs when cluster is idle".

I am finding that when the database is scaled to 0 Aurora Capacity units, the API fails.
Even if I change the API configuration to time out out after 40 seconds, it fails if the database was at 0 ACUs when it was called. Calling the API again after some time yields a successful call.

Whether at `connection.connect` or `connection.query`, the failures come with no useful response - the response just doesn't come.

I have not been able to determine if the database needs a moment to scale up to determine if I need to pause the call. Logging to the console the `connection` info looks the same whether the database is scaled down or ready for a query.

Is there a way to programmatically check if a AWS Serverless v2 Aurora MySQL database is scaled to 0? `connection.state` does not seem to describe this.

I have tried many many approaches. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59552875/nodejs-12-callback-not-working-for-mysql-connection) seemed promising, but didn't solve my issue.
What I have now is...

```
var connection;

exports.getRecords = async (event) => {
    await openConnection();
    // Simplified connection.query code that works when the database is scaled up
    var q = 'SELECT * FROM databaseOne.tableOne';
    connection.query(q, function(err,results){
        if(err) {
            console.log('q err', err);
            throw err;
        }
        console.log(results);
        resolve(results);
    })
}

async function openConnection() {
    connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: process.env.hostname,
        port: process.env.portslot,
        user: process.env.username,
        password: process.env.userpassword,
    });
    console.log('connection1', connection.state, connection);
    try {
        await connection.connect();
        console.log('connection2', connection.state, connection);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('c err', err);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you're using Serverless Aurora v2? The "Pause after inactivity feature" isn't available in v2 yet, it's only available in v1. This is documented in the highlighted "Note" area at the bottom of the Scaling section here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.html#aurora-serverless-v2.how-it-works.scaling

Comment: I just upgraded it from v1 to v2 last night by "Modify"ing the database and choosing version "Aurora MySQL (compatible with MySQL 5.7.2.08.3)" as per AWS instructions in the alert that was displayed in the RDS console. However, when I call aws rds describe-db-clusters I see EngineMode: serverless which I think is only a serverless v1 option. I removed that from the question.

Comment: I think that just upgraded/modified the version of MySQL you were running, not the version of Aurora Serverless.

Comment: You really can't. You have to send it a request to trigger it to un-pause, and then wait possibly a few minutes, for it to come up. Most database connection libraries time out way before it comes up.

Comment: Dang. Is looping requests until a response comes really the only approach? That is disappointing AWS

Comment: This is one of the chief reasons people were unhappy with Serverless Aurora V1, and why they came out with a V2 that behaves differently.

Comment: ... which doesn't have CloudFormation support. 24x7 is the way for now.

Comment: Wow, that's just sad. Terraform had Aurora Serverless V2 support without a couple days of it's release.